# ¿Cómo sería el formato del insert de valores en esta tabla?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g, insert

```
create table pedido(
            IdPedido number(12) not null,
            Empno number(10) not null,
            IdCli number(10) not null,
            fechapedido date DEFAULT trunc(SYSDATE),
            fechaact date not null,
            Importe number not null,
         CONSTRAINT PRIc_KEY PRIMARY KEY (IdPedido)
         );
```

He estado tratando pero siempre me sale un error de formato con todos
los intentos

Ejemplo:

```
insert into pedido values
('0123','123','1001','2020-01-02','2020-01-03 00:00:00', '25');
```

Me devuelve el error:

> ORA-01861: el literal no coincide con la cadena de formato

Comment: ¿Intentaste convertir los strings a date? ¿Y remover el cero inicial de `IdPedido`?

Comment: si, me faltaba convertir los strings, ahora tengo otro error con lo que es el sysdate

Answer (score 1):

Con los campos numéricos no debieras tener problema al pasar cadenas, siempre que contengan solo números pero, ya que estás pasando constantes, debieras entregarle números al motor.

En el caso de la fecha, que es la que te está dando problema, debes pasar una cadena de fecha en el formato que tiene la sesión, o bien utilizar la función `to_date()` para convertir una cadena a fecha en un formato arbitrario, por ejemplo:

```
insert into pedido 
values (123,123,1001,to_date('2020-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2020-01-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 25);
```

Como ves, paso directamente los números, no cadenas y, ya que la fecha que tenía hora, era a la media noche exacta, puedo omitirla, pues al no tener hora, asume las `00:00:00`.